# Problems with tiles in MapProxy

Tags: openstreetmap, mapproxy

I'm trying to display tiles rendered through Mapnik in Mapproxy.

I got it to work correctly for the first zoom level:

[image]

But two zoom levels in, the tiles are already combined in a wrong way:

[image]

My tiles are served through Mapnik. I followed the following tutorial:

https://www.linuxbabe.com/linux-server/openstreetmap-tile-server-ubuntu-16-04

I can display the tiles correctly through OpenLayers on a slippymap.

Here's my current mapnik configuration:

```
services:
  demo:
  tms:
    use_grid_names: true
    # origin for /tiles service
    origin: 'sw'
  kml:
      use_grid_names: true
  wmts:
  wms:
    md:
      title: MapProxy WMS Proxy
      abstract: MapProxy Configuration for mapnik

layers:
  - name: mapnik
    title: TMS layer from tiles
    sources: [osm_cache]

caches:
  osm_cache:
    grids: [webmercator]
    sources: [osm_tiles]

sources:
   osm_tiles:
     grid: webmercator
     type: tile
     url: http://10.77.70.19/osm_tiles/%(z)s/%(x)s/%(y)s.png

grids:
    webmercator:
        base: GLOBAL_WEBMERCATOR
        origin: 'sw'

globals:
```

Some layers further in, everything seems to be okay again:

[image]

Is it possible for Mapproxy to show the correct map at all? And if it's not, what are my alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a configuration that works, mostly through trial and error:

```
services:
  demo:
  tms:
    use_grid_names: true
    origin: 'nw'
  kml:
      use_grid_names: true
  wmts:
  wms:
    md:
      title: MapProxy WMS Proxy
      abstract: MapProxy Configuration

layers:
  - name: bel_mapnik
    title: TMS layer from tiles
    sources: [osm_cache]

caches:
  osm_cache:
    grids: [osm_grid]
    sources: [osm_tiles]
    format: image/png

sources:
   osm_tiles:
     grid: GLOBAL_WEBMERCATOR
     type: tile
     transparent: true
     url: http://10.77.70.19/osm_tiles/%(z)s/%(x)s/%(y)s.png

grids:
    osm_grid:
        srs: EPSG:900913
        origin: nw

globals:
```

I hope this will be helpful to somebody.

Comment: It would be much more helpful if you would describe what was wrong.

Comment: The pertinent difference seems to be using a `nw` `origin` rather than a `sw` one.